# Drawing a lot of same objects from a class in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel, graphics2d

**Answer is written by me in the bottom of the question**

I want to get a lot of 'Ates' objects in a frame. I tried a lot of examples but always failed.

In this context, I want to see a lot of rectangles which are going to left. However, there is just one and it is going faster and faster...

It does not show more than one object at the same time. Can you tell me what is the problem?

I used this code:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for(Ates a1 : StartGame.alist) // alist is an arraylist for Ates class objects
        {
            g.fillRect(a1.getX(), a1.getY(), 20, 20);
        }
        ...
```

Example creating:

```
public void sentAtes()
{
    r = rand.nextInt(471)+60;
    Ates a = new Ates(r);
    alist.add(a);
}
```

Ates class:

```
public Ates(int a)
{
    x = 700;
    y = a;
}

public int getX()
{
    return x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return y;
}

public void setX( int a )
{
    x = a;
}

public void setY( int a )
{
    y = a;
}
```

StartGame class:

```
public class StartGame extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener
{
    protected static ArrayList<Ates> alist = new ArrayList<Ates>();
    public static int cen = 0;
    ...
    public StartGame()
    {
        jp = new GamePanel();
        add(jp);
        ... 
        int delay = 10;
        ActionListener taskPerformed = new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                cen++;
                if(cen > 50)
                {
                    cen = 0;
                    sentAtes();
                }
                for(Ates a1 : alist)
                {
                    a1.setX(a1.getX()-1);
                }
                repaint();
            }
        };
        new Timer(delay,taskPerformed).start();
        ...
```

**Info:** If there is only one object, it is going left as expected.

*Answer to my question.*

In `Ates` class, you should not use `static` word for variables and use `this.` prefix to set them.

This should be work.

```
public class Ates extends JFrame
{

    protected int x;
    protected int y;

    public Ates(int a)
    {
        this.x = 700;
        this.y = a;
    }
```

Comment: you draw them all in the same place?

Comment: Are you sure all `Ates` have different *x* and *y*? Are you sure that `startGame.alist` has more than one element?

Comment: Show us `alist` and how it is created

Comment: What's the point of passing `a` as a parameter to the constructor if you're not going to do anything with it?

Comment: It was copied here by mistake. I edited.

Comment: Just for the sake of being proper and using java conventions, class names should always start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Does your Ates class have get methods for x and y?

Comment: @Schonge thanks for advice about the class names, I changed my code. I also edited the question to reply your question.

Comment: Ok, that seems in order, what is the StartGame in the for loop?

Comment: Question is detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the only other thing I can see is that your `StartGame()` is only initialised once. Therefore your `new Timer` is only called once. Because it is the timer that is causing the `ActionListener` to be created it is only ever created and run through once and therefore can never reach the stage where it will create another rectangle. The `actionPerformed()` method only runs once in the program as there is no action or loop to cause it to run again.

Comment: As you see in the -edited- question, it should not have to same in every time. Am I wrong?

Comment: No you're right, each time that method is called it'll generate a different number - I'm stumped at the moment

Comment: Now, it is zick-zacking to the left. There are not a lot of objects.

Comment: @user2670532 this is the only other thing I can see that could be causing the problem. If it isn't that then I truly am stumped hopefully someone else will be able to elaborate more on it

Comment: I am sure it is working as a loop. I wrote the values of variables in the 'actionPerformed' and also if there is one rectangle, it is working well thanks to same function.